# An artinian ring is a product of local rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, localization

I am rather confused with the last line of the argument used in [00JA, Stacks Project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00JA).

> **Lemma 00JA.** Any ring with finitely many maximal ideals and
> locally nilpotent Jacobson radical is the product of its localizations
> at its maximal ideals. Also, all primes are maximal.
>
> *Proof.* Let $R$ be a ring with finitely many maximal ideals
> $\mathfrak m_1, \ldots, \mathfrak m_n$.
> Let $I = \bigcap_{i = 1}^n \mathfrak m_i$
> be the Jacobson radical of $R$. Assume $I$ is locally nilpotent.
> Let $\mathfrak p$ be a prime ideal of $R$.
> Since every prime contains every nilpotent
> element of $R$ we see
> $ \mathfrak p \supset \mathfrak m_1 \cap \ldots \cap \mathfrak m_n$.
> Since $\mathfrak m_1 \cap \ldots \cap \mathfrak m_n \supset
> \mathfrak m_1 \ldots \mathfrak m_n$
> we conclude $\mathfrak p \supset \mathfrak m_1 \ldots \mathfrak m_n$.
> Hence $\mathfrak p \supset \mathfrak m_i$ for some $i$, and so
> $\mathfrak p = \mathfrak m_i$. By the Chinese remainder theorem
> (Lemma [00DT](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00DT))
> we have $R/I \cong \bigoplus R/\mathfrak m_i$
> which is a product of fields.
> Hence by Lemma [00J9](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00J9)
> there are idempotents $e_i$, $i = 1, \ldots, n$
> with $e_i \bmod \mathfrak m_j = \delta_{ij}$.
> Hence $R = \prod Re_i$, and each $Re_i$ is a
> ring with exactly one maximal ideal. $\square$

1. How is the "Hence $R=\prod Re_i$..." deduction made?
2. Why does $Re_i$ have exactly one maximal ideal?
3. Relating back to the statement, how is this a localization at the maximal ideals?

Comment: Answers the title question, although I guess does not completely address the post: [A finite dimensional commutative algebra is a finite product of commutative local algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/227492/29335). and [Every Artinian ring is isomorphic to a direct product of Artinian local rings](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3243164/every-artinian-ring-is-isomorphic-to-a-direct-product-of-artinian-local-rings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An important thing that is kind of suppressed is that the idempotents form a complete orthogonal family of idempotents, i.e. they satisfy
$$e_ie_j=\delta_{ij}e_j \;\;\;\text{ and }\;\;\;e_1+e_2+\dots+e_n=1.$$

To see the orthogonality, note that for $i \neq j$ we in fact have $e_ie_j \in \mathfrak{m}_1 \cap \mathfrak{m}_2 \cap \dots \cap \mathfrak{m}_n=I$. Since $I$ is locally nilpotent, $(e_ie_j)^N=0$ for some $N$. But $(e_ie_j)^N=e_ie_j$ as these are idempotent. So $e_ie_j=0$.

To see the completeness, note that $e:=e_1+e_2+\dots+e_n$ is again an idempotent (thanks to orthogonality above) and we have $e\equiv 1 \pmod{\mathfrak{m}_i}$ for all $i$. So $1-e$ is again an idempotent (one can check) and, by the same argument as above, it is contained in $I$, hence nilpotent, hence $1-e=0$. That is, $e_1+e_2+\dots+e_n=1$, as desired.

Now,

1. Any element $x \in R$ is uniquely written as a sum of elements from $Re_i$'s, $x=x(e_1+e_2+\dots +e_n)=xe_1+xe_2+\dots+xe_n$. The fact that $e_i$ is an idempotent means that $Re_i$ gets a ring structure whose unit element is $e_i$. The correspondence $x \leftrightsquigarrow (xe_1, \dots, xe_n)$ then defines the isomorphism $R \simeq \prod_i Re_i$. (Checking that this correspondence is a ring homomorphism will involve the orthogonality.)
2. Each of the rings $Re_j$ will have at least one maximal ideal, pick one and call it $M_j$. Then clearly $$\mathfrak{M}_j:= Re_1 \times Re_2 \times \dots \times Re_{j-1} \times M_j \times Re_{j+1} \times \dots \times Re_n$$
   is a maximal ideal of $\prod_iRe_i$, hence it corresponds to a unique maximal ideal of $R$. But there are only $n$ of those, so by the pigenhole principle, each $Re_j$ has only the one maximal ideal $M_j$.
3. To see that $R$ is the product of its localizations, it is enough to see that the same is true for  $\prod_iRe_i$. Well, in this case it is easy to see that the localization of $\prod_iRe_i$ at $\mathfrak{M}_j$ is naturally isomorphic to $Re_j$ (meaning that the localization map is just the projection onto the $j$th component). So the claim is true for $\prod_iRe_i,$ hence for $R$ as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot Pavel! I see that you did not use the correspondence that mentioned. May you also add on how its applied?

Comment: @BryanShih I am not sure what you mean. If you mean the one from (1), this correspondence provides the isomorphism $R \simeq \prod_i Re_i,$ so it is implicitly used in the step (3).

Comment: I mean their use of Lemma 10.31.6

Comment: @BryanShih I see what you mean. In $\prod_i R/\mathfrak{m}_i,$ you consider the idemotent $\widetilde{e}_i=(0, 0, \dots 0, 1, 0 \dots, 0)$, where $1$ is on the $i$th spot. This corresponds to an idempotent in $R/I$ by the CRT, and that can be lifted by the lemma. Tracking the isomorphism from CRT, you can see that the lifted idempotent $e_i$ is congruent to the respeciive component of $\widetilde{e}_i$ modulo each $\mathfrak{m}_j$,  that is, it satisfies $e_i \equiv \delta_{i, j} \pmod{\mathfrak{m}_j}.$